# Remove values from two arrays that aren't common in both

Tags: swift

The code below works, but I would like to know if there is a way to optimize it.  The if..else statement has redundant code.  I'm not familiar enough with array.reduce / array.map { } yet.

I have two arrays containing characters.  I would like to count the number of deletions necessary in either/both arrays so they contain the same characters.
["a", "b"]
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
would require 3 deletions.

```
        var aArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
        var bArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
        var newArray = [String]()

        if aArray.count >= bArray.count {
            for i in 0..<aArray.count {
                if (bArray.contains(aArray[i])) {

                    newArray.append(aArray[i])
                }
            }
        } else {
                for i in 0..<bArray.count {
                    if (aArray.contains(bArray[i])) {

                        newArray.append(bArray[i])
                    }
                }
        }
        print(newArray) // ["a", "b", "c"]
        let count = (aArray.count + bArray.count) - (newArray.count * 2)
        print(count) // 5
```

Comment: By optimize do you mean make it faster, more concise, shorter, or all of the above?

Comment: Have a look at [`Array.elementsEqual(_:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2949302-elementsequal). It accepts two sequences as input and lets you specify a predicate. I've never used it, but it looks like it's at least in the neighborhood of what you're trying.

Comment: Are your arrays sorted? Does the item order matter after deletions?

Comment: No, order doesn't matter at all.  Thanks.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon what about duplicates?

Comment: @ben more interested in concise than faster.  Cheers!

Comment: @Dan.. yes arrays can have duplicate values [a, b, c, a] [a, a,]  would require 2 deletions.

Comment: You might also have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/GreatBigBore/90fbdcf71fd343a311c2f62546f47f6b). If you're new to Arrays, it might be a bit deep, but it sounds very close to what you're doing.

Comment: Also your question states you would like to “count the number of deletions.” Do you want to actually count them, perform the deletions in-line, create 2 new arrays with the deletions applied, or some combination of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If optimizing performance isn't your goal so much as being concise, this approach might express what you want concisely:

For any array of `String`s `xs`, we can reduce it to an `Int` value that represents the number of its elements which are not present in another array `ys` like this:

```
xs.reduce(0){ $0 + (ys.contains($1) ? 0 : 1) }
```

What this is doing is setting an initial reduced value of 0 (the first parameter passed into the `reduce` method above).

Then for each element in `xs` is it running the closure which takes the current aggregate / reduced value (which is also the first argument passed into the closure, `$0`) and if the current element of `xs` being examined (`$1`) is contained in the other array `ys`, then 0 is added to the value (it stays the same). Otherwise the element is not contained in the other `ys` array, and the aggregate / reduced value is incremented by 1.  At the end of this `reduce` method running, it will return a value that represents the starting value of 0, incremented by 1 for each time an element in `xs` was not contained in `ys`.

To get the total deletions needed, you would just run the same `reduce` method but for `ys` relative to `xs` and add the results from each reduce together.

So in the case of your example code:

```
var aArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
var bArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
let totalDeletions = aArray.reduce(0){ $0 + (bArray.contains($1) ? 0 : 1) } + bArray.reduce(0){ $0 + (aArray.contains($1) ? 0 : 1) }
print(totalDeletions) //5
```

---

## Going Further

You can make things a little more reusable as well as clearer at the call site if you create a generic function which will produce the right `reduce` closure for any context (including any arrays that contain other Equatable values besides just `String`s), e.g.:

```
func incrementIfNotIn<T: Equatable>(_ otherArray:[T]) -> (Int, T) -> Int {
  return { $0 + (otherArray.contains($1) ? 0 : 1) }
}
```

This function takes in an array of any `Equatable` type (strings, ints, floats, or anything else) and returns a closure that take an `Int` (representing your counter value) and an element of the type that the array contains, and returns the `Int` value incremented by one if the array you specified doesn't contain the element, or not incremented at all if it does. So the same thing we did earlier, but made generic for any array of any `Equatable` type

And now we can write your example code like this:

```
var aArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
var bArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
let totalDeletions = aArray.reduce(0, incrementIfNotIn(bArray)) + bArray.reduce(0, incrementIfNotIn(aArray))
print(totalDeletions) //5
```

Or use arrays of `Int`s instead like this:

```
let aArray = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7]
let bArray = [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 13]
let totalDeletions = aArray.reduce(0, incrementIfNotIn(bArray)) + bArray.reduce(0, incrementIfNotIn(aArray))
print(totalDeletions) //8
```

And it reads more expressively I think

Answer (score 2):

Using power of `Set`s you can easily solve this task:

```
let aArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
let bArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

// first, get unique items of aArray
let aSet = Set(aArray)

// second, get unique items of bArray
let bSet = Set(bArray)

// now the cool part: find those elements, that are present only either in aSet or in bSet but not in both
let exclusive = aSet.symmetricDifference(bSet)

// count how many items in the arrays are in the `exclusive` set
let deletions = aArray.filter { exclusive.contains($0) }.count + bArray.filter { exclusive.contains($0) }.count
print(deletions)
```

Or, you can init sets inline so code is even shorter (perhaps less readable):

```
let aArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
let bArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

let exclusive = Set(aArray).symmetricDifference(Set(bArray))
let deletions = aArray.filter { exclusive.contains($0) }.count
                + bArray.filter { exclusive.contains($0) }.count
print(deletions)
```